# How to align images?

Tags: image-processing, correlation

I have two grayscale images (`img1`, `img2`) which contain objects seen with two cameras. 
Some objects are the same (not same shape and intensity) and are seen in both images.
Some objects are only seen in `img1` or `img2`.

I would like to align the images in such a way that the objects seen in both images are overlapping.

**How can I determine the vertical and horizontal shift between the two images?**

Here are the images:

`img1`:

[image]

`img2`:

[image]

What I tried:

```
pts = ImageCorrespondingPoints[img1, img2, KeypointStrength -> 0.0002]

{{{34.6035, 72.9785}}, {{48.1733, 82.9132}}}

xshift = Mean[pts[[All, All, 1]][[2]] - pts[[All, All, 1]][[1]]]

13.5698

yshift = Mean[pts[[All, All, 2]][[2]] - pts[[All, All, 2]][[1]]]

9.93468
```

This seems to be correct. When I look only at the vertically elongated object in the center of `img2` then I find manually roughly: `xshift=10`, `yshift=13`.

What confuses me:

The found points `pts` do not correspond to `img1` or `img2`:

```
HighlightImage[img1, pts]
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[img2, pts]
```

[image]

Where is the error in `HighlightImage`?

**Can `ImageCorrelate` or `ImageAlign` be used to find the shift or do you have another solution?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My solution is the following:

Determine the shift between both images:

```
{merit, trans} = 
 FindGeometricTransform[img2, img1, 
  TransformationClass -> "Translation"];
```

> [image]

Applying the shifts

```
imgt = ImageTransformation[img2, trans, DataRange -> Full]
```

Combine images

```
Blend[{ColorNegate[img1], imgt}, {0.8, 0.2}]
```

> [image]

Comment: very interesting ...

Comment: In the documentation the `TransformFunction` obtained from `FindGeometricTransform` is a transformation which if you apply to the second image in the argument of `FindGeometricTransform` (in this case img1) you get an image which is aligned with the image in the first argument (here img2). However, it seems it the other way around and by applying the `TransformationFunction` on the first argument you align it with the image in the second argument. Is this right?

Answer (score 12):

Using `ImageFeatureTrack` works pretty well:

```
{f1, f2} = ImageFeatureTrack[{img1, img2}];
HighlightImage[img1, f1]
HighlightImage[img2, f2]
```

[image: Initial Points]

[image: Same Points Identified in img2]

Now calculate the offset:

```
shift = Mean[
   Cases[f1 - f2, {x_, y_} /; NumericQ[x] && NumericQ[y]]
   ];
```

And compose the images. I used `ColorNegate` so you can see what's going on:

```
ImageCompose[
 img1,
 {ColorNegate[img2], 0.5},
 shift,
 {0, 0}
 ]
```

[image: Aligned images]

Comment: great solution, thanks