# Finding how far an image has moved a very small x distance

Tags: plotting, image-processing, image, distance

I am trying to process 200+ images (10 datasets, each set contains ~20 images) and see how much each image changes or moves compared to a starting position for a dataset. The problem is, I expect a very small displacement value, however I would need to extract that value. This is what I tried so far:

```
test= 
  Values[ComponentMeasurements[ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"], 
       "MaxCentroidDistance"]][[1]] & /@ allData2;
ListPlot[test, PlotRange -> All]
```

Output:

[image: plot with MaxCentroidDistance]

However, I am not sure how to interpret the pixel values here as they are 10 different sets and you can see how they are separated. Compare the `MaxCentroidDistance` plot to what I see when I tried `IntensityCentroid`:

[image: plot with IntensityCentroid]

The images in all 10 datasets produce similar shapes. I only expect small change in *where* these shapes are formed.

Sample:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps this would be helpful? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148800/how-to-align-images

Comment: @ydd thank you, it is. If I may ask, why can't `IntensityCentroid` show small position differences for images?